# Black SEO by competitors?

Tags: backlinks, google-penguin-algorithm

Checking the new backlinks to my website https://superbank.ru in Google Search Console I noticed many backlinks in various junk blogs pointing to my website.

One example: http://zeldesign.co.uk/shop/blog/sending-and-receiving?page=3889

I am afraid such low quality backlings can spoil my backlink profile.

There are hundreds of such backlinks pointing to my website.

Who may be doing it? Shall I disawov all those crappy backlinks?

Can such backlinks result in certain pages of my website being hit by the Penguin algorithmic sanctions?

Comment: The term for competitors trying to using bad SEO tactics as a weapon against your site is "negative SEO".   If you search for that you will find tons of advice about the practice and how to deal with it.